# Return Value of Javascript Function Slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I've currently got an iOS-like on/off slider and would like to return its value which is either 1 or 0 to a hidden HTML field.

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        initCheckBoxes();
    });

    var slideSpeed = 150;
    var leftDist = 42;

    function initCheckBoxes()
    {
        $( ".cb-slider" ).draggable({containment: "parent"});
        $(".cb-slider").mouseup(function(){

            var status = $(this).attr("cb-status");

            switch(status)
            {
            case "0":
                //its off, slide it by 41px;
                $(this).animate({left: leftDist}, slideSpeed);
                //change status to 1
                $(this).attr("cb-status", "1");

            break;

            case "1":
                //its on, slide it to 0px;
                $(this).animate({left: "0"}, slideSpeed);
                //change status to 0
                $(this).attr("cb-status", "0");

            break;
            }
    });


}
```

And the value I'm concerned with is the `var status`.

I just can't figure out how to return this value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you don't want to "return" the value but to change the hidden field's value. Add this to the mouseup event:

```
$( '#hidden' ).val( status );
```

where `#hidden` is the selector for the hidden input field.

Comment: So with your method I should add $( '#hidden' ).val( status );

then 

<input id="hidden" name="anonymous" type="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

You function applied to all elements match by the selector `$(".cb-slider")`. Are you sure you want to store the selected value of the last changed slider at a shared location?

I´m assuming you´d like to access the values of your sliders server side when you submit the form. If that´s the case you´d need some unique identification of your sliders to separate them from each other and to know which one i which.

**UPDATE**

Created a plugin example at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CdEL/)**, check it out.